# Getter returning null SessionFactory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-security

I am trying to develop Springs-Hibernate login application with springs security. When i am trying to retrieve users from DB with Hibernate. I have proper working Springs-Hibernate Configuration. Everytime getter returning sessionFactory null (I am printing address in getSessionFactory method). I have one method getLoginDetails() which is working perfectly if i am not invoking method at login time (Checked with just simple anchor tag), but when i am logging in its not working. Here is my code:

Springs-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<!-- This is where we configure Spring-Security  -->
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/auth/denied" >
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/auth/login" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/main/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/main/common" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <security:form-login
        login-page="/auth/login"
        authentication-failure-url="/auth/hi"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="myAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
    <security:logout
        invalidate-session="true"
        logout-success-url="/loggedout" />
</security:http>


<!-- A custom service where Spring will retrieve users and their corresponding access levels  -->
<bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="com.springs.service.CustomUserDetailsService"/>

<!--A service where spring will redirect to proper view after successfull login-->
<bean id="myAuthenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.springs.controller.MySimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />

<!-- Declare an authentication-manager to use a custom userDetailsService -->
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

ApplicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>classpath:jdbc.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="DataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="${c3p0.acquireIncrement}" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="${c3p0.minPoolSize}" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="${c3p0.maxPoolSize}" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="${c3p0.maxIdleTime}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.hibernate.model" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/> 
</bean>
</beans>
```

Dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<!-- Scan only for @Controllers -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.springs">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:component-scan>
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<tx:annotation-driven/>
<!--
Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
define an explicit mapping for it.
-->
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="index">indexController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />

<!--
The index controller.
-->
<bean name="indexController"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
      p:viewName="index" />

</beans>
```

CustomerUserDetailsService.java

```
package com.springs.service;
import com.hibernate.model.DbUser;
import com.springs.dao.UserDAO;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
private UserDAO userDAO ;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {

    UserDetails user = null;

    try {
        DbUser dbUser;
        userDAO=new UserDAO();
        dbUser = userDAO.getLoginDetails(username);

        user = new User(
                dbUser.getUsername(),
                dbUser.getPassword().toLowerCase(),
                true,
                true,
                true,
                true,
                getAuthorities(dbUser.getAccess()));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n");
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Error in retrieving user");
    }
    return user;
}


public Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Integer access) {
    List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authList = new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>(2);
    if (access.compareTo(1) == 0) {
        authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
    } else {
        authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
    }
    return authList;
}
}
```

UserDAO.java

```
@Repository
public class UserDAO {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    System.out.println("session factory: "+sessionFactory);
    return sessionFactory;
}

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

public int getdata(String username) {
    String hql = "select count(*) from Userdetails";
    Userdetails u = (Userdetails) getSessionFactory().openSession().get(Userdetails.class, username);
    System.out.println(u.getName());
    Long l = (Long) getSessionFactory().openSession().createQuery(hql).uniqueResult();
    return l.intValue();

}

public DbUser getLoginDetails(String username) {
    DbUser user = new DbUser();
    Userdetails u = (Userdetails) getSessionFactory().openSession().get(Userdetails.class, username);
    user.setUsername(u.getName());
    user.setPassword(u.getPassword());
    user.getAccess();
    Set userroles = u.getUserroles();
    Iterator it = userroles.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Userrole ux=(Userrole) it.next();
        user.setAccess(ux.getRollid());
    }
    System.out.println("accss is: "+user.getAccess());
    System.out.println("username is: "+user.getUsername());
    System.out.println("pw is "+user.getPassword());

    return user;
}
}
```

message in server log :

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/SpringSecurity] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is        java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.springs.dao.UserDAO.getdata(UserDAO.java:42)
at com.springs.controller.testController.getUser(testController.java:31)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
```

I am not able to figure out sessionFactory is null if i am using it at Login activity otherwise its not null. First I was missing tx annotation in xml which i added later for @Transactional annotation. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I do not see the problem. But I'd like to attache similar files from myy sample project regarding to security. I hope it helps you:

applicationContext-security.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
        ">
    <!-- HTTP security configurations -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <form-login login-processing-url="/resources/j_spring_security_check" login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t" />
        <logout logout-url="/resources/j_spring_security_logout" />
        <!-- Configure these elements to secure URIs in your application -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/login-user/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/choices/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/member/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/login/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    </http>
    <!-- Configure Authentication mechanism -->
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <!-- SHA-256 values can be produced using 'echo -n your_desired_password | sha256sum' (using normal *nix environments) -->
        <authentication-provider>
            <password-encoder hash="sha-256" />
            <user-service>
                <user name="admin" password="8c6976e5b5410415bde908bd4dee15dfb167a9c873fc4bb8a81f6f2ab448a918" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
                <user name="user" password="04f8996da763b7a969b1028ee3007569eaf3a635486ddab211d512c85b9df8fb" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans 
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
        ">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties"/>
    <context:spring-configured/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.sample.login">
        <context:exclude-filter expression=".*_Roo_.*" type="regex"/>
        <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
    </context:component-scan>
    <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="true"/>
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000"/>
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3"/>
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000"/>
        <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT version();"/>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

MyUser.java:

```
package org.sample.login.domain;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Version;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Table(name = "my_user")
@Entity
public class MyUser {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private Integer version;

    /**
     */
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 6)
    private String name;

    /**
     */
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 6)
    private String password;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MyUser [name=" + name + ", password=" + password + "]";
    }



    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getVersion() {
        return this.version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Integer version) {
        this.version = version;
    }
}
```

Comment: I debugged my project and i came to know that userDAO(autowired in customerUserDetailsService) is null. Can you please suggest me solution for this?